# In django, input C++ code submitted to editor / textarea saved to destination directory after SUBMIT

Tags: django, editor

I am using django. Suppose I have an editor (as for now I have TinyMCE implemented). I wish that whatever C / C++  code is given as an input in editor; gets saved with a desiredfilename.cpp(this is just an ordinary file, I require only C++ codes as input so I have given .cpp as extension). This file gets saved in destination directory (/home/user/Desktop/codes) of my wish other than database and exactly with same identation and spacing as in the input code. I am unable to do this. It would be nice if someone helps.

forms.py currently :

```
from django import forms
import custom_widgets
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from myapp.models import HomePage
from django.db import models
from custom_widgets import TinyMCE


cust = dict( auto_resize = True )
class HomePageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    homecopy = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
    homecopy.widget.mce_settings = homecopy.widget.update_settings(cust)
    class Meta:
        model = HomePage
        """fields = ['homecopy']
        #widgets = {'homecopy': forms.Textarea(attrs={'required':True})}    
        widgets = {'homecopy': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})}"""
```

The only bad idea I am getting is to scrape my admin page for input code and store it in a .cpp file but in that case I will not get exact code. I will lose identations and spacings.

Comment: What did u tried? Can u give us some code example? What is your desired destination directory? Out of the django directory? What is the difference between creating a text file and a cpp file for u?

Comment: did u tried to cover your code with <code> tag within the tinyMCE widget?

Comment: okay thanks a lot, do i need to scrape the admin page to save the code to a particular file, or is there any other way out.

Comment: i am not sure. i have no ide to run tinymce with django right now. But u can easily print the output of the posted data in view function. U may need some str.replace() (: